# Howto create software package in Unix/Linux?

Tags: c++, unix, boilerplate, software-packaging

How can we create a software package, so that
after extracting our software tar ball user can do
the typical steps?

```
$ gunzip < mycode.tar.gz | tar xvf -
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make install
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An alternative to the hard to understand GNU/Autools is CMake.

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/examples.html

e.g. KDE is using it.

Answer (score 6):

Look into the GNU autoconf/automake toolchain. [Here's a free tutorial/book.](http://sourceware.org/autobook/)

Answer (score 4):

In the old days, this process was done by hand. Each `Makefile` was written by hand (the file `make` uses as a sort of script). This became problematic when it came to portability, and so the `configure` script was made. The `./configure` script was written by hand for each project as well. Eventually this was automated by GNU with their `autotools` package. This consists of `autoconf`, `automake`, and a few others. While alternatives exist, particularly for `make`, `autotools` is most widely used. ...At least on GNU/Linux systems. Alternatives include the already mentioned [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/), [Boost.Build](http://www.boost.org/doc/tools/build/index.html), [Boost.Jam](http://www.boost.org/doc/tools/jam/index.html), [SCons](http://www.scons.org/), and more.

Answer (score 1):

Use autotools to create the configure script (which will generate the Makefile necessary for the last two steps), then make a tarball with all your code and stuff in it.

Answer (score 1):

rpmbuild is a command to build rpm packages

[man page](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm-snapshot/rpmbuild.8.html)

[tutorial](http://linuxhacks.org/tutorials/jakes_rpm_build_tutorial.php)

Comment: When I read the linked manpage, it doesn't seem to answer the question I believe was asked: that how do you provide a platform flexible build in the first place (i.e. help with writing configure and makefile)... rpmbuild appear to assume that you have such a thing in place.

Answer (score 1):

Autotools.

You'll need to write a configure.ac and a Makefile.am scripts.

Configure.ac is pretty easy and can be mostly autogenerated from running 'autoscan' on your source code. That will generate a 'configure.scan' file that you'll need to tweak to generate the final configure.ac file.

The Automake.am file is all based off of conventions.  You'll probably need something like:

```
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = foreign subdir-objects
AM_CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -static-libstdc++ -Wall -Werror \
    -Wfatal-errors -I blah
AM_LDFLAGS = blah

bin_PROGRAMS = mybinary
mybinary_SOURCES = \
    blah.h blah.cc
```

everything is based on a naming schema:

- dist vs nodist = should it be built
- inst vs noinst = should it be installed
- DATA = data files
- MANS = man pages
- SOURCES = source code

so dist_noinst_DATA is for data files required for building but are not installed.

Once you have both of those files you usually need to run something like:

aclocal && autoheader && automake --add-missing && autoconf

to setup autotools files required for building. This can be put in a shell script and run prior to running ./configure.